# When you type a character in EditBox - MessagBox c create the character

Tags: c, winapi

When you type a character in EditBox - MessagBox c create the character.
He can not understand - I will be grateful for the help.
[Code here](http://pastie.org/4665420)

Comment: In English, pls. What MessageBox creates and who is he, and what he have to understand?

Comment: When you press key in EditBox - create MessageBox wiht this key. (sorry for my english - Translate Google)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to catch either

**EN_CHANGE**:
Sent when the user has taken an action that may have altered text in an edit control. Unlike the EN_UPDATE notification code, this notification code is sent after the system updates the screen.

or

**EN_UPDATE**:
Sent when an edit control is about to redraw itself. This notification code is sent after the control has formatted the text, but before it displays the text. This makes it possible to resize the edit control window, if necessary.

BTW: The parent window of your edit control receives this notification code through a WM_COMMAND message.